# What is the Response object for a request call with proxies set?

Tags: python, python-requests

I looked through the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) and did not find any mention on how the response will be different if I pass in a proxies dict to the requests.request() call or not.

Thanks

EDIT: I guess what I am asking, can I tell by looking at the return value from requests.request, whether a proxy was used in the request?

Comment: What difference would you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is exactly the same. There is unlikely to be any difference between a normal response and response in which you used a proxy.